# visualstudio.com's tfs cannot find setting for exclusive checkout

Tags: tfs

I wasn't sure if this was the place to ask but I figured people here have used it.

We have been using it for a couple of weeks and it works great. The only issue we've had with it is finding where you set exclusive checkouts.

Does anyone know if this is part of visualstudio.com tfs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have Visual Studio installed and have Team Fouondation Client installed, (screenshots from VS2010)

select Team -> Team Project Settings -> Source Control

[image]

On the dialog that appears, uncheck 'Enable multiple Checkout'

[image]

Comment: you sir, are awesome! I was all over their website trying to figure that out and it's in visual studio!